# SocialAuth : Invalid Scopes: read_stream

Tags: spring, spring-social, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

I am implementing signup from facebook.

I am using latest SocialAuth spring library: socialauth-spring-2.6.jar

And I just fallowing sample application given by socialauthdemo application.

My url is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
client_id=216531348684064&
response_type=code&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mobily.com%3A8080%2FCustomerRegistration%2Fsocialauth.do&
scope=publish_actions%2Cpublic_profile%2Cemail%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_location%2Cuser_photos%2Cuser_friends%2Cread_stream
```

I am getting error this:

> Invalid Scopes: read_stream. This message is only shown to developers.
>   Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please
>   read the documentation for valid permissions at:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

I check all my workspace, where all these scoped defined, but I am not able to find them. Even I search in socialauth-spring-2.6.jar, socialauth-4.10.jar also.

Answer (score 2):

`read_stream` has been deprecated, look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-read_stream). I would suggest start with something simple such as `public_profile` and `email`.